# How to Write a Where Clause to Handle Either a Specific Value or Any Value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a report with a table in Rails where users can optionally set filters like selecting a location or picking a range of dates and update the table via an ajax request.

Can I write this where clause so that it any date/blanks or all locations?

```
@orders = Order.where('created_at <= ? AND ? <= created_at AND location_id = ?', date_order_start, date_order_end, loc_filter)
```

The query above fails on blanks (e.g., "") and if I put nils they translate to nulls in the SQL.

To solve this problem right now I have a bunch of conditional statements that check whether value is present in the ajax request and then creates a different where clause depending on the case. My current conditionals are unwieldy, error prone and not scalable.

Searches on things like "wildcard sql" end up leading me to text searches (i.e., %) which I don't think fits in this case.

I am running on Rails 3.2 with postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sometimes use an array of query statements and arguments like this:

```
queries = []
args = []
if some_condition
  queries.push("created_at <= ?")
  args.push(whatever_date)
end

if another_condition
  queries.push("created_at >= ?")
  args.push(another_date)
end

@order = Order.where(queries.join(" AND "), *args)
```

Comment: This is much better than I have now and works well in my implementation. Sorry for the delay. I was holding out hope there would be a slick ActiveRecord/SQL solution. Thanks again!